# Issue with using a modified version of a Go dependency

Tags: go, dependency-management, go-modules

So here is the situation:

I have a fork of `go-ipfs`. It depends on `go-ipfs-config`. I need to modify `go-ipfs-config` and make `go-ipfs` depend on my modified version.

I forked the `go-ipfs-config` made my changes and made sure to update the path to be that of my forked version as can be seen [here](https://github.com/dadepo/go-ipfs-config/blob/acef5a36d0a5d2a5b8a53582218e10ff9aa81d38/go.mod#L1). I confirmed that this still builds successfully by running `go build`

Then I updated `go.mod` in `go-ipfs` to use my modified version. I used the `replace` directive to signify this intention which can be seen [here](https://github.com/dadepo/go-ipfs/blob/0719ce95a83fa88e51f5e8a3350694cfca11f83e/go.mod#L110)

This is where things gets absolutely bunkers and I am no longer sure what is going on.

When i do `go mod tidy` to fetch the dependency i get the following output:

```
go: finding module for package github.com/dadepo/go-ipfs-config
go: found github.com/dadepo/go-ipfs-config in github.com/dadepo/go-ipfs-config v0.5.3
```

The crazy thing is that `v0.5.3` does not exist in github.com/dadepo/go-ipfs-config!

Also the following line get added to go.mod :

```
github.com/dadepo/go-ipfs-config v0.5.3 // indirect
```

Which can even be seen [here](https://github.com/dadepo/go-ipfs/blob/0719ce95a83fa88e51f5e8a3350694cfca11f83e/go.mod#L9)

I have run commands like `go clean -modcache` and `go clean -r` etc but does not seem to fix things!

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? And also how to achieve the goal of making my version of a project depend on another modified version of its dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is as a result of me not being aware of couple of things going on in the Go lang toolchain.

Apparently https://proxy.golang.org is a thing! It is a service operated by google that caches modules. So If you made a release, deleted it, chances are that the version is already cached in https://proxy.golang.org. This was exactly what happened in my case. I had made a 0.5.3 release, deleted it, but it is not really gone as the Google cache already got a hold of it.

So in case you are seeing versions that should not exist. This should be the first place you check. This [documentation link](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_downloading_and_verification) also sheds some more light on the proxy and how it can be tweaked.

I found this out based on the conversation I had on the issue I opened reporting this behaviour. If you are curious, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38664).